# GCC 9.2.0 build error : incorrect version of gmp.h while the version is actually correct

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, cross-compiling, gmp

I am trying to build a cross-compiler and I chose gcc-9.2.0
So when i run ( from the OSDev Wiki)

```
../gcc-9.2.0/configure --target=x86_64-elf --prefix="$HOME/opt/cross" --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers
```

I got this error

```
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for the correct version of gmp.h... no
configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+.
Try the --with-gmp, --with-mpfr and/or --with-mpc options to specify
their locations.
```

So I checked the gmp.h library and the version is 6.2.0

```
#define __GNU_MP_VERSION            6
#define __GNU_MP_VERSION_MINOR      2
#define __GNU_MP_VERSION_PATCHLEVEL 0
```

Then i tried to use the `--with-gmp` option, but i got the same error

My platfrom : `Windows 10 64-bit`

I use `Cygwin-x86_64` as a bash emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i found what was wrong. I had installed another gcc compiler for Code::Blocks and it was in PATH variable, so ./configure took this compiler and not the cygwin's